# Saving models and their relationships using the new Ember Data JSONAPISerializer/Adapter

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have implemented a JSON-API backend and I'm using ember (1.13.4) and ember data (1.13.5) to pull my data in to the store using the new JSONAPIAdapter / JSONAPISerializer. All is working well and the store is populated with all of the models and their attributes/relationships.

However, when I call the .save() method on my models the JSON-API-formatted request that is generated doesn't contain the "included" key with all related models inside it.  This means that if I modify an attribute in a related model and then save the primary model I don't see the changed attribute from the related model in the JSON payload.

What is the correct way to save models and their relationships so they are embedded using the new JSONAPIAdapter / JSONAPISerializer?  I tried the EmbeddedRecordsMixin but this resulted in null attribute values within the "attributes" key of the payload.

If anyone can assist me with this I'd be grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: Does anyone know how to get the "included" attribute to be present in the POST when saving a model with relationships as per my description above please? Do I have to manually do it by adding related records to each relationship or does the JSON-API serializer do it out of the box?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this has been answered on the Ember forum as follows:

> "The standard does not support this at the moment and is scheduled for v1.1 (http://discuss.jsonapi.org/t/json-api-weekly-meeting-june-22nd-2015/23).
>
> Your best bet would be to inherit from the serializer and implement your own standard for now. Just remember to include the included paths in your URL so that your server can reply with all the updated entities."

More information can be found [here](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/saving-models-and-their-relationships-using-the-new-ember-data-jsonapiserializer-adapter/8438?u=danr1979).

Comment: To complete this: At the time of writing, v1.1 of the spec is still not released and work in progress. I use an [ember-addon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-data-save-relationships) to compensate the missing feature in the JSONAPISerializer. My backend [JSONAPI-converter](https://github.com/jasminb/jsonapi-converter) accepts this and correctly converts the payload.